# Riemann integral and step function

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0$ if $f(1/n) = 1$ for $n = 1,2,... $ and $f(x) = 0$ for all other $x$.

I want to prove this by using step functions but I don't know how to.

So I need to show that for $\epsilon >0$ there exists a step function $f_1(x)$ such that $0\le f(x) \le f_1(x)$ and that $\int_0^1 f_1(x)dx < \epsilon.$

Comment: Hint: How would you do it for the function $g_N$ defined by $g_N(x)=0$ for every $x$ except $g_N(1/n)=1$ for every positive integer $n\leqslant N$?

Comment: @user104235: What are your candidates for $f_1(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Surround each point $\frac 1 n$ with an interval of length $\epsilon 2^{-n}$.